# Import Json into dataframe python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to import JSON from a webpage into a dataframe, it's my first time trying to do this and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I would like to get a dataframe with two columns from calendarEntries: productCode, settlement

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import os
os.chdir('D:/')


def scrape(url):
    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers.update(
        {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0'})
    time.sleep(rd.randint(0, 10))
    response = session.get(url, params={"_": int(time.time() * 1000)})
    return response


def main():
    option_url = f'https://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/ProductCalendar/Options/138'
    response = scrape(option_url)
    expiration=pd.read_json(response)
    print(expiration)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Could you please explain what is going wrong with your code, if you are getting an error please add the error message to the question

Answer (score 1):

pd.read_json accept file or buffer, but response is just a http response, modify to `pd.read_json(response.content)` works